# react native use the new lifecycle for animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is a sample of react native [animation](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-motion/blob/master/src/TranslateX.js):

the core step is in old lifecycle **componentWillReceiveProps**:

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.value !== nextProps.value) {
      this.move(nextProps.value);
    }
  }
  move = toValue => {
    const { style, type, ...rest } = this.props;

    Animated[type](this.state.translateXValue, {
      toValue,
      ...rest,
    }).start();
  };
```

now **componentWillReceiveProps** is deprecated, new lifecycle in react component update become:

```
* static getDerivedStateFromProps
* shouldComponentUpdate
* render
* getSnapshotBeforeUpdate
* componentDidUpdate
```

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is static so no `this` is in it, it seems we do not have the timing to call `move` function before `render`. how should we write the sample component with new lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

After some study, the code in `componentWillReceiveProps` should be moved to `componentDidUpdate` with little change.

```
  componentDidUpdate(preProps) {
    if (this.props.value !== preProps.value) {
      this.move(this.props.value);
    }
  }
```